# Function to input key and value from dictionary, extract line of data from given input location (csv file), and output the line of data

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have `megadict`, a dictionary with matching keys and values that correspond to headings and lines in a csv file. The function `fill_lists` is supposed to input a key and value, turn the key into an empty list, then fill that empty list with data from the corresponding value. This function works as intended for single calls to the function, but fails when iterating over the dictionary. How can I change my code so that it will iterate over `megadict`, turn each key into a list, then fill each list with data from the corresponding value? Thanks!

CSV File: Campus_Culture3.csv

```py
user,year,university,school,
U1,Sophomore,Temple University,Fox School of Business
U2,Sophomore,Drexel University,School of Business
U3,Sophomore,The Catholic University of America,School of Theatre
```

Program

```py
megadict = {'user': 0, 'year': 1, 'university': 2, 'school': 3}

import csv 
filename = "Campus_Culture_Test3.csv"
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    def fill_lists(key, val):
        key = []
        for line in csvreader:
            key.append(line[val])
        del key[0]
        print(key)
```

Input

```py
 for key, val in megadict.items():
        fill_lists(key, val)
```

Desired Output

```py
['U1', 'U2', 'U3']
['Sophmore', 'Sophmore', 'Sophmore']
['Temple University', 'Drexel University', 'The Catholic University Of America']
['Fox School of Business', 'School of Business', 'School of Theatre']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We cannot effectively help you until you post your MRE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: You haven't supplied the dict; `csvreader`  is undefined.  I'm a bit confused about your concepts, as a dict key cannot be a list.  The code fragment you posted, without a calling program or demonstrated output, is not sufficient to describe your problem.  Perhaps read through [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) again.

Comment: You immediately overwrite the `key` parameter?? I agree with @Prune, you need to make a [mre] and read [ask]. BTW welcome to Stack Overflow! If you want to ease yourself in, try taking the [tour] first.

Comment: @Prune Thank you for for your feedback, sorry my post was so unclear. I have added what seems to be the minimal, reducible example of code, along with a link to the CSV file. Please let me know what other information you need. As you can probably tell, I am very new to coding, so all help is appreciated.

Comment: @wjandrea Thank you! I have edited my post to include what I think is the minimal reducible example and included the CSV file in the link. Thank you for your patience, let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @rpsutton That's great progress, but you're still missing the expected output. Also you need to put a minimal version of the input in the question itself.

Comment: We generally need a representative csv file: not an image, not an off-site link.

Comment: @wjandrea Ok I have added both an input and desired output, as well as a representative CSV file.

Comment: @Prune Ok I have added a representative CSV file, as well as a minimum input and desired output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*(This started as a comment but it got long and complicated.)*

I think you're trying to use `key` as a pointer, but that's not how Python works. It's more like a reference, though because it's immutable, it behaves like a value. Anyway, the point is that when you assign to `key` in the function, it's local to the function. You need to either pass in the dict to fill, construct the dict in the function and return it, or return a list and assign it to the dict in the surrounding scope.

But that said, this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832). You want to read in a table and extract its columns, but your algorithm reads the table and extracts a column, then reads the table again and extracts the next column, etc. It would make more sense to read the table *once* and *then* extract its columns. How to do that is another question which I'll leave up to you, though one approach is `pandas.dataframe`.

Comment: Some of my terminology about low-level stuff might be wrong. Please correct me!

Comment: Not sure why the downvote... I'd appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
d={'head1': 'line1', 'head': 'line2', 'head2': 'line3'}
l=[]
for key,val in d.items():
    entry=[key,val]
    l.append(entry)
```

If you dont want the key and you want it to be an empty value, then insert
a `key=''` between line 3 and 4

now maybe you meant something like this??

```
l=[]
for val,info in zip(d.values(),csvreader):
    entry=[val,info]
    l.append(entry)
```

output:

```
[['line1', 'information1'], ['line2', 'information2'], ['line3', 'information3']]
```

Comment: You could shorten these using list comprehensions among other things, e.g. the first one: `l = [list(t) for t in d.items()]`, or if you don't mind tuples instead of lists, simply `l = list(d.items())`. Although I don't think that's what OP is looking for.